# How to print a message when a Pane is empty?

Tags: 7, panels, comments

I've rewritten the node pages on my website with a Panel page (using *node_edit*) and added the node's comments as a Pane. When no comments have been published yet, the Pane is hidden. However, I'd like to still display the Pane's title and a sentence underneath that says something like: *Be the first to react.*

I already have a template `panels-pane--node-comments.tpl.php` and added some lines under `if(!$content}{print t('Be the first to react.');}`, but as the Pane isn't displayed, the template isn't activated. What should I do?

I know that I could create a View that shows all the node's comments and set a value when there aren't any, but maybe that's overkill?

Comment: Rather than figuring out this pane business, I would approach this specific comment secenario as, if comment count equals 0, print be the first to react.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create a new pane with that text and set a visibility rule on it - there should be an existing rule that you can use. If not a ctools rule plugin is pretty simple to write and you can have that rule plugin check to see if comment count is 0.

Answer (score 0):

Add another pane (text area holds the string) to be displayed if the comment count equals 0.